# Plugin crashed n Cypress

Tags: cypress

My tests were running without a problem, after I pulled the updates from the main branch and switched to mine, I got the following error:

```
**Title:** Error running plugin

**Message:** We stopped running your tests because a plugin crashed.

Your `pluginsFile` threw an error from: `D:\Repos\vjtrk\cypress\plugins\index.js`

**Details:** CompositeParserException: Parser errors:
(66:0): unexpected end of file, expected: #DocStringSeparator, #Other
    at Function.Errors.CompositeParserException.create (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\errors.js:27:13)
    at Parser.parse (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\parser.js:72:45)
    at module.exports (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\cypress-cucumber-preprocessor\lib\loader.js:29:33)
    at Stream.end (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\cypress-cucumber-preprocessor\lib\index.js:24:18)
    at _end (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\through\index.js:65:9)
    at Stream.stream.end (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\through\index.js:74:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.onend (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:577:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:events:402:35)
    at endReadableNT (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)


**Stack trace:**
```

```
at Function.Errors.CompositeParserException.create (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\errors.js:27:13)
at Parser.parse (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\gherkin\lib\gherkin\parser.js:72:45)
at module.exports (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\cypress-cucumber-preprocessor\lib\loader.js:29:33)
at Stream.end (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\cypress-cucumber-preprocessor\lib\index.js:24:18)
at _end (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\through\index.js:65:9)
at Stream.stream.end (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\through\index.js:74:5)
at DestroyableTransform.onend (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:577:10)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
at DestroyableTransform.emit (node:events:402:35)
at endReadableNT (D:\Repos\vjtrk\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:1010:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue by removing the multi-line comments in the feature file.